# SAS libname syntax to connect to SQL Server via ODBC

Tags: sql, sas, sql-server-2014

I've googled for a few days and can't get this working.

I'm using SQL 2014 and the adventureworks database.

I've got SAS 9.3.

I've tried different ODBC settings, as in setting a default database, using Windows login, or SQL login. Different drivers. Still nothing, used complete and noprompt:

```
libname mylib odbc complete='TrustedConnection=True;DSN=test2;SERVER=MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=AdventureWorks2012;'stringdates=yes;
proc print data=mylib.Person;
```

Error message:

> NOTE: Libref MYLIB was successfully assigned as follows:
>         Engine:        ODBC
>         Physical Name: test2
>
> NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.
>                 Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is
>                recommended.
>
> NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
>   NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
>         real time           5.48 seconds
>         cpu time            0.34 seconds
>
> 700  proc print data=mylib.Person;
>   ERROR: File MYLIB.Person.DATA does not exist

I've tried with `Person.Person` and also in the connection string using `schema=Person`.

However if I use the following it works. I put the default database in the ODBC:

```
proc sql;
   connect to odbc as mycon
   (required = "dsn=awlt32;uid=sa;password=mypassword");
   select *
   from connection to mycon
      (select *
      from Person.Person);

disconnect from mycon;
quit;
```

I know this is a super simple question but I can't seem to get it working, no matter what example code I find. Thanks in advance.

Comment: NOTE 49-169 should disappear if you put a blank before stringdates=yes

Comment: Any idea with the:700 proc print data=mylib.Person; ERROR: File MYLIB.Person.DATA does not exist

Comment: If you run `proc contents data=mylib._all_;` do you see any tables?    I don't know adventureworks. Could it be you need to add a schema name to the libname statement?

Comment: I've tried with the schema name in the connection string and using mylib.Person.Person., AdventureWorks in a MS test DB.

Comment: It looks like your quotation mark ends too early? Stringdate should be in quotes and semicolon after the connection string. Also try adding schema=dbo and note that table names are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Reeza, I haven't tried it with schema=dbo. Will try that later today.

Comment: `schema=Person` looks like it's the right thing to use here if table `person` is in the `Person` schema.

Comment: Got it working. schema=Person is correct, but I had never tried it in the libname statement but outside of the " " connection string. opps. All fixed. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the database connection to your ODBC driver; you will need the name of this connection in your libname,
2. Use the libname below and update the datasrc, sql user and password

`LIBNAME mylib ODBC  DATASRC=name from step1  SCHEMA=dbo  USER=sql user  PASSWORD="xxx" ;`

```
proc datasets lib=mylib ;
quit;
```